# Difference between "(у)видать" and "(у)видеть"

Tags: словоупотребление

I've seen **увидал** used where one would use **увидел**. Is there any difference in meaning, or perhaps register?

> Когда он **увидал** фото, он просто сломался.

Comment: There's also _видывать_. ))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perfective *увидать* and *увидеть* don't really differ.

Imperfective *Ты это видел?* and *Ты это видал?* would mean "Did you see that" and "Have you seen that?", respectively. This I think is the closest thing Russian has to English perfect and simple past distinction.

Historically, *видать* is an iterative for *видеть* (same as *летать / лететь*, *плавать / плыть* etc.)

However, this form is not productive in Russian anymore, so some of historical iteratives either have completely merged with their base forms (*стелить / стлать*) or acquired idiomatic meanings like those above.

Comment: And wha about повидать?

Comment: @VCH250: it does not have a counterpart from *видеть*

Answer (score 2):

"увидал" is just a demotic form of "увидел".